# Searching for an Event Simulation Software with SOAP API

Tags: soap, discrete-mathematics, event-simulation, arena-simulation

I’m trying to build a showcase for a business activity monitoring (BAM) tool. In my showcase the BAM tool is fed via a soap api with events. Now I’m looking for an event simulation tool like [arena](https://web.archive.org/web/20210526213605/https://www.arenasimulation.com/what-is-simulation/discrete-event-simulation-software) which is able to trigger my soap api every time an event went through a simulation step in the event simulation tool. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should check out the help section.  Pay particular note to item #4 in the section about [off-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. It's possible to include VBA bricks in arena:

**Step1: Activate VBA blocks in Arena**

Open "Basic Process" then right click on Create. Go to Template Panel and click on Attach. Then select `Blocks.tpo`and open.

---

**Step2: Process ID**

Add an ID Attribute as well as a StartID as a Variable. Than you can use the following VBA code to assign an incrementing ID to all entities. To do that just add the following VBA code as a brick behind your Create brick ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adjyG.png)).

```
'Assign ID Attribute to Entity
Private Sub VBA_Block_2_Fire()
   Dim s As SIMAN
   Set s = ThisDocument.Model.SIMAN
   Dim NewCounter As smDataType
   Dim CurCounter As smDataType

   CurCounter = s.VariableValue(s.SymbolNumber("IDStart"), 0, 0)
   NewCounter = CurCounter + 1

   s.SetVariableArrayValue s.SymbolNumber("IDStart"), NewCounter
   s.EntityAttribute(s.ActiveEntity, s.SymbolNumber("ID")) =       NewCounter

End Sub
```

---

**3 Step: Add the SOAP API as VBA brick behind each Process brick**

Then add another VBA brick after every process brick. This VBA brick then contains a SOAP call. I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4586c62e-7e10-4b7d-923a-f18b7dc6515c/calling-a-webservice-wsdl-from-office-2007-with-vba-without-using-vsto-2008?forum=isvvba) page useful to build a SOAP service in VBA. Before you can do that, you have to activate Microsoft XML, 6.0 in VBA under Tools --> References